# Would I be allowed to give Bitcoin tips for answers?

Tags: support

Often times I'm really impressed by the quality and detail of answers given. I'd love to show my appreciation in the form of a tip, either directly to someone's Bitcoin address or via something like changetip: https://www.changetip.com/how-to-send-tips/

Changetip already works on quite a few sites including Github, Reddit, Twitter, and Youtube.

Comment: You could ask them in the chat for an address

Comment: Many people don't hang around or are even aware of chat. Does stackexchange even have a private message system? Can't seem to find it on profile pages.

Comment: there is no PM system but if you use @ username in the chat the user will get the message in there notifications bar

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is just a bit different than

[**Is it okay to ask for money donations in an answer?**](https://bitcoin.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/460/is-it-okay-to-ask-for-money-donations-in-an-answer/461#461)

but not by much. There are a lot of intrinsic motivations for why people contribute their time and their knowledge to this site, but receiving payment or "tips" isn't one of them. While I appreciate the gesture, it really is not warranted or even particularly helpful to this site.

There's also the issue of user solicitations in general (which are not allowed). Asking people for contact information can get ugly fast. There's this whole realm of *"I'll send you free stuff for your contact info"* spam that would not be allowed on this site. So we just don't allow these types of solicitations at all.

So while I cannot control how you interact with user *off* this site, I do ***not*** think it's a good idea to **encourage or allow users to solicit contact information for the purposes of payment or anything else.**

Interesting question. Thank you for bringing up the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed and clear reply. Still a bit surprised that GitHub, which I thought had a similar philosophy, does accept tips.

Comment: Would it be acceptable to provide links like these on our profiles?

Comment: @DantheMan Yes, we provide a lot of latitude for what people can put in the 'about me' section of their profiles (i.e. not patently offensive, abusive, hate speech, illegal, etc). So a bit of self promotion or contact information is perfectly acceptable in a profile; it's not part of the main Q&A. But that doesn't mean posts ending with "Go read my profile to tip me" are any less a solicitation.

Comment: The idea with ChangeTip is that you pay what you want if you like something or appreciate the answer.

It is not a way to ask for compensation. (or at-least should not be used as such)
If ChangeTip where supported, and anyone asks for a tip - then that would/should be grounds for a ban or similar action. But if I really like a answer, question or even a comment, it would be nice to express that with a small tip.